# Boundary of disk bundles over surfaces

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two $D^2$ bundles over a (not necessarily orientable) closed connected surface $\Sigma$.  I looking for necessary and/or sufficient conditions that show that $\partial X_1 = \partial X_2$.  As I guess, maybe we need the Euler classes to be equal up to sign?

Comment: Does $\partial X_1 = \partial X_2$ mean homeomorphism? Does $\Sigma$ have empty boundary?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes and yes - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you want both disk bundles to be orientable or nonorientable simultaneously (a bundle is orientable iff it is trivial over the 1-skeleton of the base). For orientable bundles with orientable base ("totally orientable"), the $\pm$ Euler number is the complete invariant; otherwise the Euler number is not even well-defined. However, one can define the "virtual Euler number", obtained by taking a finite totally orientable cover $p: X'\to X$ and setting $e(X):= e(X')/deg(p)$. I think, this is a complete invariant. Check ["The geometries of 3-manifolds"](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2012_MA4J2/geometry.pdf),  Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society (1983), by Peter Scott.

Comment: I can see just by homology considerations that the Euler class distinguishes the boundaries of the orientable disk bundles over orientable surfaces.  However, how does one see that this is a complete invariant the boundaries over say $\mathbb{R}P^2$?

Comment: @user101010: My answer was only in the totally orientable case and $RP^2$ is not. For the general case, as I said, take a look at Scott's paper.